# How to blow up disk space fast

Tags: python

I am trying to blow up a directory in my docker container to test maintenance scripts. I've tried logging to a file in an indefinite while loop -- this was extremely slow. Fast way to do this programmatically?

Comment: You want to exhaust disk space but not memory space?

Comment: You could just pipe `/dev/random` to a file? `cat /dev/random > somefile`

Comment: If using the `dd` command, "direct" can speed things up. `dd if=/dev/zero of=deleteme bs=10M oflag=direct count=100` writes a gig, skipping the OS cache.